# How can I shard OrientDB?

Tags: scale, sharding, orientdb

I want to shard OrientDB to run on multiple servers, but I couldn't find a true way to do it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sharding will be provided with 2.0.0 planned for December 2012/January 2013. Right now you can have multiple distributed databases.

Comment: It is now June 2013. What is the status of 2.0 version release or sharding features for OrientDB?

Comment: It has been postponed to work on the new "plocal" storage engine (more durable on crashes) and new index implementation.